# How can I make an IF Formula that depending on the number it will use Floor.Math or it wil use Ceiling.Math?

Tags: excel

I want to have comercial prices ending in 90, For example:

- $3.945 = $3.890  ---> floor.math($3.945, 1000) - 10
- $3.955 = $3.990  ---> ceiling.math($3.955, 1000) - 10

So I want to make an IF that when $x.x5x it uses ceiling.math    (5 and up)
but when it is $x.x4x it uses floor.math    (4 and down)

Also when its $xx.x5x it uses ceiling.math  (5 and up)
and when its $xx.x4x it uses floor.math    (4 and down)

¿Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think rounding price to 1 decimal and then substracting 0.01 should do the trick. Formula: `=ROUND(A1,1)-0.01`

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The formula for this is:

```
=Round(Price,-1)
```

Example:

- 32.256 --> 32.260
- 32.249 --> 32.250

```
=Round(Price,-2)
```

Example:

- 32.251 --> 32.300
- 32.249 --> 32.200

```
=Round(Price,-3)
```

Example:

- 32.251 --> 33.000
- 32.249 --> 32.000